# Launching separate NWJS App from within a NWJS app onclick of a button

Tags: javascript, html, nwjs

I'm working on a launcher application for software. Cant seam to figure out how to launch another application onclick of a button in my NWJS app. I've done it before on an HTA back in the day to launch my video games, but cant seam to figure it out on here. On the hta I had to spawn a bat file on click then the bat script ran the program.

My button I've made:

```
<span name="SystemWrapper3" id="SystemWrapper3" class="SystemWrapper3">
    <input type="button" value="Calculator"    name="SystemInput3" id="SystemInput3" class="SystemInput3" />
    <i class="fa-solid fa-square-root-variable fa-lg" id="SystemIcon4"></i>
</span>
```

I've been looking into it I'm still pretty new to this. I've tried several solutions I've found looking stuff up online but they failed to work. idk if it is version incompatibility or what? I'm using NWJS 0.64.1 Win64 It may or may not end up being a NWJS app I'm launching, it might be just a regular exe. I'm not sure if there is different requirements for doing both.

EDIT::::

I've found this but I'm not sure how to call this code onclick of my button? Maybe make it a function? Then call the function name with onclick="myfunc()"?

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

exec('C:/asd/test.exe', function(err, data) {  
    console.log(err)
    console.log(data.toString());                       
});
```

EDIT2::::

So i tried this and several variations and still no luck. i called it from my button with onclick="launchbat()".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function launchbat() {
        var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

        exec('"C:\Users\Dustin Angeletti\OneDrive\Documents\bat.bat"', function(err, data) {  
            console.log(err)
            console.log(data.toString());                       
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I was reading on childprocess but its not working. I deleted my snippet i was messing with because i got frustrated ahaha I almost quit this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Quite simple my first approach and second works fine. My problem the whole time was using backslashes like in the true file path. You have to use forward slashes. Very odd. This works for relative and absolute paths.

```
function AppLaunch7() {
    const path = require('path');
    nw.Shell.openItem(path.resolve('D:/SECURE DRIVE/SYSTEM CORE/SECURE CALC/SECURE CALC.exe'));
}

<div name="SystemWrapper1" id="SystemWrapper1" class="SystemWrapper1" onclick="AppLaunch7()">
    <input type="button" value="Documents" name="SystemInput1" id="SystemInput1" class="SystemInput1" />
    <span name="SystemIcon1" id="SystemIcon1" class="material-icons">description</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Though depending on what you want, you may want to use `require('child_process').spawn` instead of `require('child_process').exec`.

**Vanilla JS:** You need to set up each button (repetitive) and update the array.

```html
<button id="calculator">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-square-root-variable fa-lg"></i>
  Open Calculator
</button>

<button id="photoshop">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-aperture fa-lg"></i>
  Open Adobe Photoshop
</button>

<script>
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const path = require('path');

const appMap = [
  {
    buttonId: 'calculator',
    executable: 'calc.exe'
  },
  {
    buttonId: 'photoshop',
    executable: path.join('C:', 'Program Files (x86)', 'Adobe', 'Photoshop', 'photoshop.exe')
  }
];

function executionCallback (err, stdout, stderr) {
  if (err) {
    console.log({ err });
  }
  if (stdout) {
    console.log({ stdout });
  }
  if (stderr) {
    console.log({ stderr });
  }
}

appMap.forEach(function (app) {
  const button = document.getElementById(app.buttonId)
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    exec(app.executable, {}, executionCallback);
  });
});
</script>
```

**Vue.js:** You can use Vue instead, here all you need to update is the array and Vue will handle everything else.

```html
<div id="app">
  <button v-for="app in apps" @click="run(app.executable)">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-lg" :class="app.icon"></i>
    {{ app.label }}
  </button>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.36/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script>
const exec = window.nw.require('child_process').exec;
const path = window.nw.require('path');

const app = Vue.createApp({
  data: function () {
    return {
      apps: [
        {
          icon: 'fa-square-root-variable',
          label: 'Open Calculator',
          executable: 'calc.exe'
        },
        {
          icon: 'fa-aperture',
          label: 'Open Adobe Photoshop',
          executable: path.join('C:', 'Program Files (x86)', 'Adobe', 'Photoshop', 'photoshop.exe')
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    run: function (appExecutable) {
      const options = {};
      exec(appExecutable, options, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
          console.log({ err });
        }
        if (stdout) {
          console.log({ stdout });
        }
        if (stderr) {
          console.log({ stderr });
        }
      });
    }
  }
}).mount('#app');
</script>
```

Comment: I ended up finding some what of a solution however it lacks the extras that's what you posted has. i used: function AppLaunch1() { nw.Shell.openItem('AppLaunch1.bat'); } and then called the function with onklick="" I'm going to go back over that part though with the information a provided and see what other functionality i can get out of the whole child process thing.